# One requirement file for multiple projects

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have 2 projects on GitHub and I use Docker and an identical requirements file for both projects. The problem is that these files must be identical.

Do you know if it is possible to use a single "requirements.txt" file for both projects, or if there is a way to update both files (on github) so that they are identical after a modification ?

Any help appreciated, thank you !

Comment: At a Docker level you could create one base image that installed that `requirements.txt` file and build two derived images `FROM` that...but developing is still going to be a hassle, as will changing both projects in exact unison.  Why do you need to only have one set of package dependencies?

Comment: Another way is you could create a git submodule and have the requirements.txt in that by itself